# Ansible - iterate over multiple hashes in a single play

Tags: ansible

I have a data structure in a json file that gets fed to ansible as an extra variables file, and it looks something like this:

```
"files_from_ftp":
{
   "file1":
   {
      "full_name":"very-long-file-name-1"
      "url":"ftp://.....very-long-file-name-1.zip"
   },
   "file2":
   {
      "full_name":"very-long-file-name-2"
      "url":"ftp://.....very-long-file-name-2.zip"
   }
},
"files_from_network":
{
  "file3":
  {
     "full_name":"very-long-file-name-3"
     "network_path":"file:///SOMEWHERE/ON/THE/NETWORK/very-long-file-name.zip"
  }
},
"files_from_s3":
{
  "file4":
  {
     "full_name":"very-long-file-name-4"
     "url":"s3://some.s3.bucket/very-long-file-name-4.tar"
  }
}
```

These three sections specify files that are downloaded from different sources.

They come from different sources, and it is know that some of them are different types (tar files come from s3, zip from the local network and ftp server) so I have three different plays to handle each download. But at the end of each play, there is a file whose name is the value of `full_name` (all entries in these hashes **will** have an element named `full_name`) in the directory `/home/ubuntu/downloaded_files`.

*After* they are downloaded, they are all processed in the same way. Right now, I have three separate plays that do the same thing, but iterating over a different hash, like this:

```
- name: process files from ftp
  shell: some_command -f /home/ubuntu/downloaded_files/{{ item.value.full_name }}
  with_dict: files_from_ftp | default({})

- name: process files from network
  shell: some_command -f /home/ubuntu/downloaded_files/{{ item.value.full_name }}
  with_dict: files_from_network | default({})

- name: process files from s3
  shell: some_command -f /home/ubuntu/downloaded_files/{{ item.value.full_name }}
  with_dict: files_from_s3 | default({})
```

I'd like to be able to have a single play that handles all of these hashes, but I am not sure if this is possible. I can't seem to figure out the syntax. What I'm thinking of in *hypothetical* (and probably syntactically invalid) code:

```
- name: process all downloaded files
  shell: some_command -f /home/ubuntu/downloaded_files/{{ item.value.full_name }}
  with_dict: ( files_from_s3 | default({}) )
             and ( files_from_ftp | default({}) )
             and ( files_from_network | default({}) )
```

In this code sample, I'm imagining that `with_dict` will iterate over a union of the three other hashes.

Does this make sense? Is what I want to do even possible? It would be easier to change the plays than the data structure since the data structure in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think you should change from using a hash of files to a list of hashes. However:

In Ansible 2.0 you'll be able to do a `hash_merge` like so:

```
- shell: echo "{{ item.value.full_name }}"
  with_dict: files_from_s3|hash_merge(files_from_ftp)|hash_merge(files_from_network)
```

Which you can already configure by adding this [hash_merge filter plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkk/ansible/merge_hash/lib/ansible/runner/filter_plugins/hash_merge.py)

Comment: Nice! For more information, here is the link to the PR: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/7872

Comment: The files are broken into different hashes because some are downloaded using the `get_url` module, others with s3, others are copied over the local network. After they have all been downloaded and preprocessed, there are some common steps that are identical and applied to all. If they were all in one single hash, the later steps would be easy, but I'm not sure how I'd write one single play that can download from either S3, local network, or ftp server, and then execute one of several other pre-process steps.

Comment: Well, complexity in this case is seeming to get to the point you'd want to write a module for managing this, it would be better capable of handling corner cases like files overriding other files, files that are outdated, etc. And the truly special case of idempotency